# Working with colors in ASP.NET using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, colors

I am currently trying out some things in asp.net and ran into following issue: 
I have currently 2 color pickers, button and label like:

```
 <input type="color" runat="server" id="colorPick1" name="colorPick"/>
 <input type="color" runat="server" id="colorPick1" name="colorPick"/>
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Mix Colors" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
 <asp:Label ID="resultMix" runat="server" ForeColor="White" style="text-align: center" BackColor="White"></asp:Label>
```

the idea is that I take the 2 colors, munch them into algorithm and write something into label with text color that is returned via the algorithm. Basically it would be something like:

```
private Color algorithm(Color c1, Color c2){ 
Color c;
//do something
return c;
}
```

My visual studio couldn't even find the "using System.Windows.Media;" so that the Color class of C# would be visible. Is there some elegant solution to this?

I use the C# in my page, not VB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`System.Drawing.Color`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

There are methods like

1. `Color.FromName(strng name);`
2. `Color.FromArgb(int red, int green, int blue);`
3. `Color.FromKnowColor(Color color);`